# JS - Show one FAQ at a time, hide others

Tags: javascript, html

[FAQ fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BneGL/2/)

JS code:

```
var $ = function (id) {
return document.getElementById(id);
};
var faqs = $("faqs");
var h2Elements = faqs.getElementsByTagName("h2");

var h2Node;
for (var i = 0; i < h2Elements.length; i++) {
    h2Node = h2Elements[i];


}
$("first_link").focus();
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("h2").click(function () {
        if (h2.hasAttribute("class")) {
            h2.removeAttribute("class");
        } else {
            h2.setAttribute("class", "minus");
        }
        if (h2.nextElementSibling.hasAttribute("class")) {
            h2.nextElementSibling.removeAttribute("class");
        } else {
            h2.nextElementSibling.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Upon clicking a question, that answer should show. When I click on a different question, all other answers should retract (be hidden). I tweaked it a few times and either the code wouldn't hide anything (all answers still open) or all answers wouldn't open at all.

Starting from $(document).ready(function () {, how do I get the question to open one at a time when clicked (close others)?

Any input would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a function to hide all other `div`'s having class name `open`, like:

```
function hideOthers() {
    var othersDivEle = document.getElementsByClassName("open");
    for(var d = 0; d < othersDivEle.length; d++) {
        othersDivEle[d].removeAttribute("class");
    }
}
```

and change your code in :

```
...
} else {
   hideOthers();
   h2.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("class", "open");
}
```

to

```
..
} else {
    hideOthers();            
    h2.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("class", "open");
}
```

Updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BneGL/7/)